# how to store instance methods name of a class in a column in sql database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a column that has nested hash structure.

structure of that column:

```
   column_name: company
   { production=> {watch=> "yes",pen =>"no",pencil => "yes"}
      quality => {life_test =>"yes", strong_test =>"yes", flexibility_test => "no"}
    }
```

Here  production, quality are my models and watch, pen, pencil, life_test,strong_test are my instance method of respective classes. each instance method will get the Boolean value from the view page. 
    How to achieve this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called serialization and it is pretty easy. You could do the following:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :company, JSON
end

bar = Something.new
bar.company = { :production=> {:watch=> true,:pen => false, :pencil => false}
      :quality => {:life_test =>true, :strong_test =>true, :flexibility_test => false} }
bar.save
```

If you want more info go here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html and read the part on "Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns" just make sure your company column in the database is a text column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Here i have a issue ,I have a model something which doesn't have a table in Active record and has a instance methods. I want to add a column company in 'features' table

Comment: The model doesn't have a table at all in the database?

Comment: Yes.That model does't do any thing new just share some work of all other models like calling mailers for sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use serialization to store hash in db .

Follow api [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html)